# Unable to Parsing nested Json file in C#

Tags: c#

I have Json format response from a API call and I want to map the data from the response to each varibales.

Json format

```
{
 "success": true,
  "data": {
    "students": [
      {
       "Admission_date": "2018-05-01",
       "Name": "Sree",
       "Branch": "Electronics",
       "Semester": "2",
       "HOD": "Mahesh",
      },
  {
      "Admission_date": "2018-05-01",
      "Name": "Naresh",
      "Branch": "Electronics",
      "Semester": "2",
      "HOD": "Mahesh",
      }
              ],
     "remaining": 0
    }
    }
```

I have tried to parse the JSON response and then to load the value through for each. But I'm not able to achieve the solution.

```
JObject jsonparsing1 = JObject.Parse(str4); //str4;- Json value
var token1 = (JArray)jsonparsing1.SelectToken("data");
var token2 = (JArray)jsonparsing1.SelectToken("data[0]Students");
JArray abc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(token2.ToString());

foreach (var test in abc)
{
String Admission_date=test["Admission_date"];
String Name=test["Name"];
String Branch=test["Branch"];
String Semester=test["Semester"];
String HOD=test["HOD"];
String remaining=test["remaining"];
}
```

Expected result

```
String Admission_date=Admission_date
String Name=Name
String Branch=Branch
String Semester=Semester
String HOD=HOD
String remaining=remaining
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: [This](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is your friend

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `var token1 = (JArray)jsonparsing1.SelectToken("data");` - `data` isn't an array, it's an object. That *may* be what's going wrong - but it's hard to tell as you've not told us what happens with the code you've provided. (It's good that you've shown us the code and the expected result, but please provide the actual result as well.) As a side note, I'd strongly recommend starting to follow .NET naming conventions for local variables etc - so `admissionDate` rather than `Admission_date`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will follow your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this sample:

```
public class JsonData
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
         this.students = new List<Student>();
    }

    public List<Student> students { get; set; }
    public int remaining { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public string Admission_date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Semester { get; set; }
    public string HOD { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
JsonData abc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(token2.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you.
I have tried this code. But after
     var token2 = (JArray)jsonparsing1.SelectToken("data[0]Students");
it jumps to catch section. Could you please help me to understand what will be the reason

Comment: I change my code to solve your problem, Read from this link to know about json.Net: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @ Sreepu If its helpful for you please accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

I will do this way!

```
public class Student
{
    public string Admission_date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Semester { get; set; }
    public string HOD { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Student> students { get; set; }
    public int remaining { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

and in C# Code Just use only below line:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{ \"success\": true,\"data\": {\"students\": [{ \"Admission_date\": \"2018-05-01\",\"Name\": \"Sree\",\"Branch\":\"Electronics\",\"Semester\": \"2\",\"HOD\": \"Mahesh\",}],\"remaining\": 0}}");
```

use

```
foreach(var item in obj.data.students)
{
  // Access  Admission_date etc.
  string name = item.Name;
}
```

[`dotnetfiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MqboRq)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this. I get the value of "remaining" as 0. But the "students" have null.

Comment: Show the value of `str4`?

Comment: Yes, above code works. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I have given upvote yesterday itself. I don't understand where I can mark this as answer.

Comment: @Sreepu there is tick mark just below that upvote and downvote option click that tick